# Setting the $SHELL environment variable

Tags: linux, macos, unix, shell, zsh

For some reason, when I run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`, my `$SHELL` environment variable isn't getting set. When I run:

```
echo $SHELL
```

It outputs:

```
/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`chsh` does only affect subsequent logins, not the shell you are currently running.

Try to log out and log in again or restart your graphical system or display manager. `$SHELL` should then be set, if the `chsh` command succeeded.